# htaccess redirect subdomain to subdirectory without duplicate in url/address bar

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect some subdomains to subdirectories, but want to preserve the requested URL.

For example:

**sub1.example.com**

Should redirect to `/public_html/sub1` and the URL should remain **sub1.example.com**

I also have a few sub-subdomains, and those should redirect as follows:
**nested.sub2.example.com**

redirect to `/public_html/sub2/nested` and the URL remains **nested.sub2.example.com**

Currently, my htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)lnested.sub2\.example\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/nested.sub2/
RewriteRule ^ /sub2/nested%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)sub1\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub1/
RewriteRule ^ /sub1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

I have this 90% of the way there. There are some problems.

If the URL is missing the trailing slash () I sometimes get something like:
**sub1.example.com/sub1/**

And some other times I just get a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not want to *redirect* requests at all, you want to internally *rewrite* them:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%2/%1/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%2/%1/$1 [L]
```

These rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it didn't work. I am using Cloudways and they don't give root access.

Comment: Could you add an example URL please?